# Compare queries on converted columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

Certain parts of my database are required to be extremely flexible to the point that the user might decide to manipulate number and/or data types of columns in a table. The data that is already in the table though should be preserved.
That leaves me with the only option of using `nvarchar(max)` as the data type for any column in any of those tables.

Be it the case that the user chooses to store integers in a certain column and then wants to get all rows with that field in a certain range. Then I should run a compare query over converted values of that column into `int`.

I am afraid that would a performance disaster. Assuming that I am left with no other design alternatives, what can I do to improve some performance in this scenario?

Comment: It will not only be a performance disaster, but it will also complicate all of your queries by first assuring that the value that you need to convert is actually of the data type that you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can relate to this problem.  An application, for instance, might be taking user input from an Excel spreadsheet and need to store this in a format as the user sees it.  Once in the database, though, you might have other requirements on filtering and combining data.

You've solved half the problem.  By storing the value in a character field, you can store what the user wants.

The second half is to store the value also as a reasonable way for the database to manipulate.  I would decide on a set of base types, perhaps just float and datetime, depending on the application.  Then, when a user inserts a value, you can do the conversion and set the value in a separate columns.  Your table might have columns like this:

```
ColumnX_WhatTheUserSees nvarchar(max),
ColumnX_Type char(1) not null default 'C',  -- 'C'haracter, 'F'loat, 'D'atetime
ColumnX_Float float,
ColumnX_Datetme
```

The insertion logic then goes something like this:

```
insert into t(ColumnX_WhatTheUSerSees, ColumnX_type, ColumnX_Float, ColumnX_Datetime)
    select @ColX,
           (case when isnumeric(@Colx) = 1 then 'F'
                 when isdate(@Colx) = 1 then 'D'
                 else 'C'
            end),
           (case when isnumeric(@Colx) = 1 then cast(@Colx as float) end),
           (case when isdate(@Colx) = 1 then cast(@Colx as datetime) end)
```

The above code is meant for illustrative purposes only.  You may need to handle special cases you are not interested in (perhaps you think '1e5' should be a string or you might want to handle numbers with parentheses as negative numbers).

You can handle the extra part of the update through a before insert or before update trigger, so the user would never see the extra complexity.  You can provide a view so the user sees only the "WhatTheUserSess" columns.

Finally, SQL does offer the `sql_variant` data type.  This provides an alternative route for what you want.  However, it would lose the initial user formatting (which has been important when I've encountered similar problems).

Answer (score 1):

Given what you said, perhaps you could add an additional int column for each column and a trigger that will populate it as an int if the user puts one in the nvarchar(max) column) then at least you would only have to convert the data once, rather than each time you query it. Otherwise , yes you are stuck with the poorly performing conversion to an integer (whcih is problematic since you have to preserve earlier information that may not be int) in order to do any kind of ordering or mathmatical calculation. Another possibility is to have a string column and an int column (and a trigger to make sure only one of the two is populated) and then a view that coalesces them for display for when you ned to show all records. A meta table to tell you which one the client is using could help you in wswrting queries.  No matter what this is a mess. Have you considered that a nosql solution might be better for your requirment?? That is the use case for NoSQL, data athat is unstructured. If we knew the real use for this data, it is possible we could suggest a better design alternative.

(Turn Rant on - Personally, without knowing more, I would question the need for any application to be that flexible. Often requirements add more flexibility than users actually require or will use and developers dutifully build it. I have seen this in every single COTS program I have had to support. Users in general think they want flexibility - making it a sales point, but find it so hard to use that they will not use it in practice. Sometimes we need to do a better job of pushing back when the requirement will make the software run slowly or be virtually unusable. Turn Rant off. )

Comment: It's actually a wiki engine and this is the part for [wiki template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Templates) generator.
The thing is the data inserted as template parameters are to be query-able. hence the need for type switching and converted queries.
I think a version of what you offered (having a generic string column and one type-specific column for each type change) would work.